# Shortcut key to special characters

Tags: keyboard, mac, macos

I'm developer from Belgium, so I'm using an AZERTY keyboard,  and for some reason Apple has a reduced AZERTY keyboard compared to the QWERTY keyboard, some special charters like `{}` & `[]` The `{`can be made with the <kbd>⌥</kbd> key and <kbd>(</kbd>, but for the `[]' isn't such a key available, so is there a way to make a keyboard shortcut to those? Could be helpful since I'm a PHP developer, otherwise I'll consider to buy an QWERTY keyboard.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the Apple French or Belgian azerty layouts, [] should be at option plus shift plus ().